# CTS and GTS queries

Tags: android, cts

I have some queries about CTS testing.

We are using Windows 7 system with 64-bit and 8GB RAM and CTS test suite “android-cts-5.1_r3-linux_x86-arm”.

We are running CTS 5.1_R3 which has 200000+ test cases. I have following doubts:

- No test case is getting executed after executing the test case
  `org.apache.harmony.jpda.tests.jdwp.Multisession.RefTypeIDTest`. CTS
  took 18.5 hours to reach that test case and hangs after executing
  that test case. What is the solution for this?
- How much time does CTS testing takes to complete? Are two SIM cards
  required to run CTS on a dual SIM phone?
- What is the estimated time to complete CTS-Verifier testing?
- Can we carry on GTS testing parallely with CTS or first CTS should be
  completed, then we can start GTS? What is the requirement for GTS?
  Does it require any license? If so, then who has to provide the
  license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the estimated time to complete CTS-Verifier testing?

CTS Verifier you can complete within 3 hours.

> How much time does CTS testing takes to complete? are two SIMS required to run CTS on a dual SIM phone?

Only one device it will take 2 days for Lollipop and Marshmallow.
you can connect more than 3 devices then it will take 7 to 8 hours to complete the CTS.

> We are running CTS 5.1_R3 which has 200000+ test cases. I have below mentioned doubts- • No any test case is getting executed after executing the test case org.apache.harmony.jpda.tests.jdwp.Multisession.RefTypeIDTest. CTS took 18.5 hours to reach that test case and hangs after executing that test case. what is the solution for this?

run `cts --plan CTS --disable-reboot`

Comment: There is no manual way to recover if the device(s) hangs while execution .. as the cts report will dump at last i.e after completion. For that we can have a script shell/python to disconnect the adb while running cts and dump the report in between or at some particular package. and continue further with continue-session option ... for NE cases

Answer (score 2):

How much time does CTS testing takes to complete? are two SIMS required to run CTS on a dual SIM phone?

> > CTS test takes time for:
> >     Lollipop: 30-36 hours
> >     Mashmallow : 48-54 hours
> >     You can reduce the time by using 3 or more devices with shards command
> >     run cts --plan CTS --shards 3
> >     or if using more than 1 device, you can run CTS optimizer tool which will thoroughly distribute the TCs to each DUT and will complete the Test in optimal time.
> >     for andorid mashmallow CTS Rerun use below command if test is not getting executed:
> >     run cts --continue-session  --skip-precondtions
> >     --disable-reboot

About 25-40 Tcs are there related to SIM card, you can rerun those TCs with 1 DUT and only SIM in 1 slot is required no need to place SIM in 2nd slot.

What is the estimated time to complete CTS-Verifier testing

> CTS Verifier is basically a Manual Test
>   it takes 3-4 hrs to complete the Test but in mashmallow Camera ITS takes a lot time and efforts to get completed.